# Can not open tomcat default page CentOS

Tags: centos, tomcat

I have downloaded tomcat on my local box and when i try to run in the is the output which i have.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/user/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.23
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/user/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.23
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/user/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/user/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/user/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

The output from `netstat -plntu`

```
Proto    Recv-Q    Send-q      LocalAddress   Foreign Address    State                                                                  
tcp6        3           0      0 :::8080       :::*              LISTEN
```

When i try to open ip:8080 there is no page loadeded.

Comment: Check `iptables -L` if you are blocking access, also check for possible SELinux denials?

Comment: I did not see any blocking access. Also i tried to get the resposnse using wget but still i have nothing. I`m using ip v4.

Answer (score 0):

First, try it from the local server (for instance with `wget localhost:8080`) and see whet it gives you. If it works, some firewall (either on the network or on the machine) is preventing you from accessing; else try to access the manager app on `/manager` to see if it works.

I wonder if the tomcat user has access to your home directory, because it should have access to catalina home. Try `su - tomcat` and try to `cd` to your `CATALINA_HOME`

Your access logs could help you (and us) diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The output from netstat -plntu

```
> Proto    Recv-Q    Send-q      LocalAddress   Foreign Address    State
> tcp6        3           0      0 :::8080       :::*             
> LISTEN
```

> When i try to open ip:8080 there is no page loadeded.

I’m not sure if you are using the ipv4 or ipv6 in your test. Try testing through the loopback interface.

Note that it is only listening on the ipv6 (tcp6) protocol. 127.0.0.1 would be the ipv4 loopback address. Try using ::1 to test instead.